# UK visa application processed: no visa, no refusal letter

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, application-status

I just got back my passport. When I opened the package, it contained only my passport with absolutely nothing else in it, and not even a refusal letter was sent to my email (I checked my spam, main box, promotions etc.)
They sent me only the following message:

> Dear Applicant,
>
> Your passport and supporting documentation are now ready for collection at the TLScontact UK Visa Application Centre. You can collect your documents in person or by a representative.
>
> Collection in person
>
> Please provide following:
>
> - Your Application Checklist
> - Your Original Photographic ID
> - Copy of Your Photographic ID

I don't know what to do. How can I find out what has happened?

Comment: have you been through the passport to see if a visa was added?

Comment: @AMAR MRIZAK If the visa isn’t in your passport, the only option you have to find out what has happened is to contact the visa processing centre or consulate where you applied.

Comment: i already applied twice before , they were rejected and sent me refusal letters , but at this time only  ( Your passport are now ready for collection ) should i contact UKVI ?

Comment: I am in exactly the same boat at you. I received emails on 22 January and 10 March saying that a decision has been made on my visa. However, there's neither a visa nor a denial in my passport. There's only the passport. Would you mind updating here when you find out more?

Answer (score -3):

Your documents are always sent separately from the visa refusal letter. If you haven't received a letter yet, wait a few days.

Comment: UKVI sent a message  : Thank you for the information you have provided.

We escalated your case to the relevant department on 11/03.  You should be contacted regarding your case within 15 working days from the date of escalation. 

Your patience is highly appreciated.

Comment: That isn’t true. The refusal letter is always included with the document. There is no “approval letter”.